# Adding two categories to a same product in Sanity.io

Tags: next.js, sanity, headless-cms

How I can assign two categories to the same product in sanity schema? like a shirt could be in Featured Category as well as Shirt category. So, all I want is to add an option so that I can attach 2 categories to the same product. Stucked since yesterday.

Code is given below:

Product Schema:

```
export const products = {
  name: "products",
  title: "Products",
  type: "document",
  fields: [
    {
      name: "title",
      title: "Product Title",
      type: "string",
    },
    {
      name: "price",
      title: "Product Price",
      type: "number",
    },
    {
      name: "discount",
      title: "After Discount",
      type: "number",
    },
    {
      name: "image",
      title: "Product Image",
      type: "image",
    },
    {
      name: "description",
      title: "Product Description",
      type: "string",
    },
    {
      name: "care",
      title: "Product Care",
      type: "string",
    },
    defineField({
      name: "category",
      title: "Product Category",
      type: "reference",
      to: [
        {
          type: "category",
        },
      ],
    }),
  ],
};
```

Category Schema:

```
import { defineType } from "sanity";

export const category = defineType({
  name: "category",
  title: "Category",
  type: "document",
  fields: [
    {
      name: "name",
      title: "Category Name",
      type: "string",
    },
  ],
});
```

Is there anyone who can help?